# Can you make <label> tags keyboard-focusable in Safari/Chrome/old Firefox?

Tags: html, keyboard

In HTML, if you want to make arbitrary elements keyboard-focusable, you can add the attribute `tabindex="0"` to them (as per e.g. http://snook.ca/archives/accessibility_and_usability/elements_focusable_with_tabindex).

The HTML5 spec *sort of* ratifies this by making the `tabindex` attribute legal on any element:

- http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/editing.html#sequential-focus-navigation-and-the-tabindex-attribute
- http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/index.html#attributes-1

However, as far as I can tell, this doesn’t seem to work for `<label>` elements in Chrome and Safari, or Firefox until 3.6 (and there it stops the user from tabbing any further through the page once they reach the `<label>`).

- http://jsfiddle.net/TaCC3/

Is there any way to make `<label>`s keyboard-focusable in Safari/Chrome, and/or older versions of Firefox?

Answer (score 2):

I think that the whole purpose of the label tag is to set focus on other elements and not on itself.